# Tensorflow cannot detect CUDA enabled device

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu

I have an RTX 4070 on my Dell XPS laptop that also comes with an Intel IRIS Xe Graphics card. I am using Windows 11.

I have NVIDIA Graphics Driver Version 535.98 installed on my system and has support for CUDA versions up to 12.2. I need to use CUDA 11.2 and that's what I have installed on my system.

```
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
```

is what I get with `nvcc --version`.

I am working on a project that produces an exe upon compilation. The project exe expects multiple dlls including `tensorflow_cc.dll` since the neural network code is based out of tensorflow. Upon running the application, I receive the following error.

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

and then application proceeds to run successfully from there on (although a lot slower since it is running on the CPU).

I am able to run the `DeviceQuery` sample from NVIDIA successfully. `DeviceQuery` detects 1 CUDA capable device (Device0 = NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU) with CUDA Driver Version 12.2 and CUDA Runtime Version 11.2 as expected.

I have tried everything I could to debug this issue - renistalled CUDA 11.2 as well as the NVIDIA drivers but with no success. I know that this question has been asked and answered multiple times before but nothing works for me. I have already set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable as `0`.

In order to debug further, I tried `GPUtil. getAvailable()` which returns `[0]` (Device 0 detected as GPU) when run on a Python interpreter. I wanted to try running `torch.cuda.is_available()` as an additional test to debug but I am just unable to install a GPU supporting version `torch` with `pip`. Installation of `torch` for me always results in a `+cpu` version. I have tried installing all kinds of previous and current torch versions from the pytorch website with `+cu110`, `+cu111`, `+cu113`, `+cu115`, `+cu116`, `+cu117`, etc but it fails each time with the following error:

```
pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.10.0+cu111 (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.0+cpu, 2.0.0+cu117, 2.0.0+cu118, 2.0.1, 2.0.1+cpu, 2.0.1+cu117, 2.0.1+cu118)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.10.0+cu111
```

The same with `torchvision` or `torchaudio`. All I can pip install are `+cpu` versions. Until 2021, pytorch did not offer support for CUDA 11.2 and I could have probably ascribed my CUDA version to be the issue but not anymore - Pytorch does offer support till CUDA 11.7 now.

**UPDATE 1:**

`tf.test.is_gpu_available()` returns `False` and `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` returns an empty array on a python prompt. And yes, I have already tried installing a `tensorflow-gpu` version already but that has been removed now and the packages `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` are reportedly identical since version 2.1. I installed a 2.12.0 version with pip.

**UPDATE 2:**
I heard tensorflow 2.12 is only GPU compatible on Mac OS and Linux. So I retried with tensorflow 2.10.0 but am receiving the same result.

**UPDATE 3:**
I can now get both torch and tensorflow to detect the GPU using `torch.cuda.is_available()` and `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` respectively in python. But my issue is still unresolved. The tensorflow dll is unable to detect a CUDA compatible device.

**TL;DR**

With CUDA 11.2 installed on my system, tensorflow is unable to find a CUDA enabled device even when I have an RTX 4070. I can even find it successfully under display adapters in Device Manager.

Comment: It's not recommended to use anything less than CUDA 11.8 with an RTX 4xxx series GPU.  Do as you wish, of course.

Comment: Also see this: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/fail-to-use-4070ti/17447